# Calling a psql command from a Groovy script

Tags: groovy, postgresql

I am writing a groovy script which needs to copy data from a file into a table ( Postgres Database). 
I could use the SQL command COPY, but that requires the script to run as superuser ( which is not an option I can use). The other alternative is to use \COPY, which is a psql command. But psql is a command line tool for PostgresSQL. Is there a way to call \COPY from within the Groovy script?

I tried the following:

```
// groovy method to populate table
populateTable( tableName, filePath ) {

    def command = """psql -U<database name>"""
    def proc = command.execute()                
    proc.waitFor()                                

    command = """ \\COPY $tableName FROM '$filePath' WITH DELIMITER AS ','"""
    proc = command.execute()                
    proc.waitFor()  
}
```

What I am trying to do in the above code is log onto to the psql command line and then run the \COPY command, but I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "\COPY": java.io.IOException: error=20, Not a directory
```

Just wondering if it is possible to call \COPY from a script? If not, is there any other way I can bulk copy the data from the file to the table? Its a huge file, and copying row by row will be very inefficient.

Thanks so much in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is currently executing two separate things `psql` and `\COPY` (which isn't found given the error message you entered). I'm not as familiar Postgres as MySQL, but looking at the `psql` [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-psql.html) it looks like you can pass in the command to run using `-c` parameter:

```
def populateTable( tableName, filePath ) {
    def sql = """ \\COPY $tableName FROM '$filePath' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' """
    def command = """psql -U<database name> -c "$sql" """
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the code above. When I expand out  def command, this is what I get:

Comment: Do you get an empty string or was there a problem in the cut and paste?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the code above. When I print out def command, this is what I get: 'code' psql -Usomedatabase -c "\\COPY tablename FROM 'filename' WITH DELIMITER AS ','" 'code' I copied and pasted this on the command line, and the command executed just fine. But when I run it from the script, I get errors which indicate that the double quotes surrounding the command (after the -c argument) are not recognized. If I remove the double quotes when I run this command from the command line, I get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Phuong - I am trying to figure out the editing tool here :-). Ignore the 'code' in the above post. I was trying to insert the line as code.

Comment: It might be a problem if you cut and pasted the code above. If that's the case, then take the double-quotes around `$sql` and manually type in the double-quotes. 

Alternately, another error might be if the \\COPY command is only outputting a single backslash. If this is the case, then add another couple of backslashes like this `\\\\COPY`.

Finally, if you're still having problems with the double-quote, you can try replacing them with single-quotes, but then you'll have to escape the single quotes in the `sql` variable: `\\'$filePath\\' ... AS \\',\\'`